# Behavior of mmap'd memory on memory pressure

Tags: linux, memory, large-files, mmap

I have a large tar file (60GB) containing image files. I'm using `mmap()` on this entire file to read in these images, which are accessed randomly.

I'm using `mmap()` for the following reasons:

1. Thread safety -- I cannot seek an ifstream from multiple threads.
2. I can avoid extra buffering.
3. I get some caching (in the form of a requested page already being resident.)

The question is what happens when I've read every image in that 60GB file? Certainly not all 
of the images are being used at once -- they're read, displayed, and then discarded.

My `mmap()` call is:

```
mmap(0, totalSize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED | MAP_NORESERVE, fd, 0);
```

**Here's the question: does the kernel see that I've mapped read-only pages backed by a file and simply purges the unused pages on memory pressure?** I'm not sure if this case is recognized. Man pages indicate that `MAP_NORESERVE` will not require backing swap space, but there doesn't seem to be any guarantee of what happens to the pages under memory pressure. Is there any guarantee that the kernel will purge my unneeded pages before it, say, purges the filesystem cache or OOM's another process?

Thanks!

Comment: The kernel knows that your pages are ephemeral. Only the source of the kernel knows if it will make intelligent use of that information. Google 'swappiness' for a headache.

Comment: You can use `madvise` to give it "advice" on what you're doing with the memory. I'm not sure how well it makes use of your advice, but a `MADV_DONTNEED` on regions you know you're done with at least won't hurt anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A read-only `mmap` is largely equivalent to `open` followed by `lseek` and `read`. If a chunk of memory that's mapped in a process is backed up by a file, the copy in RAM is considered part of the disk cache, and will be freed under memory pressure, just like a disk cache entry created by `read`ing from a file.

I haven't checked the source, but I believe `MAP_NORESERVE` makes no difference for read-only mappings.

Comment: You say that a page mapped in in this way is counted as part of the disk cache -- do you have a source for that? Thanks!